# Can anyone identify these 1x1 round tapered pieces?

Tags: part-identification, instructions

Can anyone identify these pieces?

[image]

Source: http://bsg.deckdesigns.de/minis/raptor/raptor.htm

[image]

Source: http://www.moc-pages.com/moc.php/26424

Answer (score 5):

The first piece is [424 Technic Hub / Handle 1 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=424):

[image: piece pic]

It's actually pretty rare, [only appearing in 9 sets from 1995-2006](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=424&in=S), and likely to stay that way as it has a similar newer counterpart, [18654 Technic, Pin Connector Round 1L](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18654) which probably replaces it.

I cannot identify what those bottom black inverted slopes are though. It looks kinda like [Wedge 6 x 4 Triple Inverted Curved](https://img.bricklink.com/ItemImage/PN/85/43713.png), but without the middle 2 studs up front.

Comment: Thanks, that's the first one (never would have found that I guess). Got any Ideas for the second? There are some more images at the source, but all somewhat blurry. Looks like this one, but with inverted roof at the sides:
(https://i.imgur.com/ruy9ZMm.gif)

Comment: @Christian Sorry, I missed that image. I can't identify it either, I've never seen a piece exactly like that.